# How to change background color of inner circle of highchart doughnut chart?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, next.js

## Need to change background color of highchart doughnut

#### Expected Result

[image]

#### Acheived Result

[image: With Background Color change]

`JS Fiddle Link : https://jsfiddle.net/shantanugade/f5ojh13z/1/`

Need help with this!! Thanks in Advance!

### Update: - I tried Changing background color -

Result
[After Adding background color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyZsO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Highcharts.SVGRenderer` class to add a circle as the background:

```
    chart: {
        ...,
        events: {
            load: function() {
                var center = this.series[0].center;

                this.renderer.circle(
                        center[0],
                        center[1],
                        (this.plotHeight - this.spacingBox.y * 2) / 2)
                    .attr({
                        fill: 'green'
                    }).add();
            }
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/oghbp479/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#circle

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change the RGB value on the chart object;

```
  chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: 0,
        plotShadow: false,
        height: 175,
        width: 175,
        margin: 0,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(250,251,236,1)' //this is the background of the whole chart, so change it to this RGBA value.
    },
```

and if you want the third value to not be white but instead to blend in with the background color change the last value on colors array on plotoptions

```
plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false,
                    distance: -10,
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'bold'
                    },
                    backgroundColor: "#fafbec"
                },
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                },
                borderColor: '',
                // center: ['50%', '50%'],
                size: '100%',
                colors: ['#000000', '#e45456', '#fafbec'], //here the last one is the color of the last line, which in the jsfiddle is white, you have to change it to '#fafbec' which is the hexadecimal equivalent of the 'rgba(250,251,236,1)'

            },
            series: {
                states: {
                    inactive: {
                        opacity: 1
                    }
                }
            },

        },
```

Comment: Yes, i tried to add background color but it applies background color to container. I just wanted to color inner circle.

Comment: Not the background color with CSS, but on the chart objects.

See the code attached, replace it in JSFiddle at the required place and it will work

Comment: Code changes as per suggestion. https://jsfiddle.net/shantanugade/f5ojh13z/9/ Problem here is whole container have the same background i.e '#fafbec' . But i only want inner circle to be colored as '#fafbec'.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lqutsoj5/ this shall do the trick.